# PHP print/store specific day date

Tags: php

I'm having some difficulty defining for print and store a specific day of week date in PHP.  It is in effect:

The next Tuesday AFTER next midnight Friday from current datetime.

This is for online orders where the process is:

Orders are taken until a cutoff time of Midnight Friday; and
Delivered the Following Tuesday.

I can't just use next Tuesday as orders between Saturday and Tuesday will be delivered the following week.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Once I have that core, I will then need to adjust a little for different shipping zones or to allow for public holidays - likely via a CSV file.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "The next Tuesday AFTER next midnight Friday from current datetime."

Comment: Example: If now=friday, the next tuesday after midnight friday will be +4 days away. On the following day, saturday, the next tuesday after midnight friday will be +10 days away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a variation of this should give you what you need:

```
$now       = new DateTimeImmutable();
$dayOfWeek = $now->format("w");
$addDays   = new DateInterval("P" . ($dayOfWeek == 6?10:9 - $dayOfWeek) . "D");
print $now->add($addDays)->format("Y/M/d");
```

Conceptual approach used: Identify "now". Identify what day of the week "now" is. Print the date of the Tuesday following the nearest forthcoming Friday.

Additional notes:

1. if $now is a Friday, then the nearest Friday is considered to be
   today
2. Saturdays require slightly specialised handling due to the
   numbering of days-of-the-week

Hope it helps